# What does negative vaccine efficacy mean in the attached article?

Tags: vaccine, covid

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC8816388/pdf/main.pdf

In the above article in figure 2, which is on page 8, the diagram shows vaccine effectiveness over time. At a certain breakpoint, it enters into the "negative" part of the vaccine efficacy graph. I'm not sure how to interpret this. Can someone shed some more insight onto how to correctly interpret this graph?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vaccine efficacy refers to some relationship between a vaccinated and unvaccinated group; there are multiple ways to measure this, see for example this Q&A on Biology: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/96941/what-does-vaccine-efficacy-mean

A quote from the specific article you reference is:

> The HR was used to calculate vaccine effectiveness using the following
> formula: vaccine effectiveness=(1 – HR) × 100%

HR here is "[hazard ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hazard_ratio)", from a Cox regression. HR = 1 would mean that the control and treated population have the same hazard (events per unit time); HR < 1 would mean the treated population has a lower hazard; HR > 1 would mean the treated population has a higher hazard.

As you can see in the formula above, that means that HR > 1, where the treated population has higher hazard, would give a negative number for "vaccine effectiveness", because *1 - (some number greater than 1)* is a negative number.

In the figure you reference, note that there is a shaded region. From the figure caption:

> The association is shown using proportional hazards models with 95% CIs
> (shaded areas) and restricted cubic splines

95% CIs are a measure of uncertainty; the correct interpretation is that 95% of the time, the range indicated by the 95% CI will include the true value. You'll see that in their figure, this shaded area includes 0 at 9 months, so even though the line is below zero, there is not enough evidence to conclude that the hazard is different in vaccinated vs. unvaccinated at 9 months.

[Cubic splines are a smoothing method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothing_spline); restricted means that the algorithm forces a linear relationship at the edge knots. In this case, you should be cautious that lines drawn at the edges may exaggerate trends earlier in the data; imagine if you just drew a straight line through a function that is asymptotic towards zero: it would eventually cross zero even though the true function never does.

Another reason that you might see higher hazards in vaccinated individuals would be if those individuals suspected they were vaccinated (for example, they experienced side effects) and therefore changed their behavior to take more risks (like occupying crowded spaces). If vaccine efficacy wanes while behavior remains changed, those individuals might get sick more often.

In plain language, I would interpret this figure as indicating "vaccine efficacy declines over time; by around 7 months the infection risk is not distinguishable between those vaccinated and unvaccinated"

Comment: Thanks for the answer Bryan. I really appreciate it. I'm still somewhat confused at what negative vaccine efficacy means? Specifically when referring to figure 2 on page 8. I have never heard of a vaccine having negative efficacy before and wanted to know how to properly interpret it.

Comment: @BishopD If a vaccine **actually** had negative efficacy, that would mean the vaccine made you more vulnerable to being sick. That's what I wrote above: "HR > 1, where the treated population has higher hazard, would give a negative number for "vaccine effectiveness". However, a more likely explanation for these data are a combination of extrapolation (the model fitting a downward efficacy trend over time and eventually crossing zero because that's what happens when you fit a line) and random chance (like if you flip a coin 10x and get 7 heads it doesn't mean the coin isn't a fair 50/50 coin).

Comment: Krouse thanks again for the explanation. I really appreciate it.